# Howto setup a LDAP server on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ldap

Question: I need to setup a LDAP-Server on my windows (7) machine for development purposes.

How do I do that?
And how do I get data in there?

Answer (score 8):

There is apparently an [OpenLDAP bundle for Windows](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200706/msg00211.html).

You could also try [ApacheDS](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/).

Regarding data access, [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) (standalone or as an Eclipse plugin) is fairly good (it's not specific to ApacheDS, it works fine against Active Directory and OpenLDAP servers too, for example)

Comment: Correct link to ApacheDS - http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/

Answer (score 3):

There's also AD LDS (Lightweight Directory Services) - used to be ADAM (Application Mode)

Answer (score 2):

Try [OpenDS](http://www.opends.org).